# Rounding of bits during different arithmetic operation in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new to HDL coding.

I have a problem regarding rounding and there are different types of rounding available, like `Round half away from zero`, `Round half to even`, `Round half to odd` etc. (found in `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding`). I wrote a verilog code of rounding for my multiplication, addition etc. with the help of internet and the code is working properly. But, I want to know what type of rounding the code is performing. Whether it is Round half to odd or Round half to even or anything else. Can anybody tell me what type of rounding the code is performing? The code is given below

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module rounding();
    parameter  x = 16;
    parameter y = 8;
    reg [(x)-1:0] A=16'b0010011010110011;
    reg          [(x)-1:0] B;
initial begin
 B = (A[y-1:0]) >= (1 << y-1) ? (A >>> y) + 1 : (A >>> y);
$display("%b", B); 
end 
endmodule
```

If I give input `A=16'b0010011010110011`; output is coming as `0000000000100111;`
if `A=16'b0000111100001111;` output is coming as `0000000000001111`

Comment: There is no rounding in your code. Everything is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code divides input value `A` by 256 and apply rounding to the nearest integer:

```
A=16'b0010011010110011 -> 9907 (dec) -> 9907/256 = 38.69 (round up) ~ 39 -> 0000000000100111
A=16'b0000111100001111 -> 3855 (dec) -> 3855/256 = 15.06 (round down) ~ 15 -> 0000000000001111
```

Comment: No, it is round to nearest. There are no advantages or disadvantages. It all depends on your application of this technique. Does it meat your requirements?